# How can I git checkout with just last commit ignoring all previous commit?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have pushed some credentials to remote origin master in few commits.

There are many changes and wanted to just remove the credential.

Say:

```
Local Branch:  A->B->C->D1->E1->F1(HEAD) (master)
                     |->lC1->lD1->lE1->lF1 (l_abc) 

Remote Branch:  A->B->C->D1->E1->F1(HEAD) (master)
```

The credentials pushed by mistake in E1 
So I removed some commit and made the HEAD at D1 in remote and local master

```
git reset --hard HEAD^^      
git push -f origin master
```

Now the structure is 
Say:

```
Local Branch:  A->B->C->D1(HEAD) (master)
                     |->lC1->Dl1->lE1->lF1 (abc) 

Remote Branch:  A->B->C->D1(HEAD) (master)
```

Even in `Local: lC1->lD1->lE1->lF1` I have those credentials, 
So I can;t merge this as this will again create those commits with credentials,

Is there a way where I can checkout  `lF1->lG1` after removing credential to other branch with just one last commit `(lG1)` and ignoring the previous commits ?

Comment: Instead what you want to do is `git rebase -i C` and edit each commit to remove the credentials. Then force push that. You could also use `git-filter-branch` to automate the process if there's a lot of commits, but if there's only a few it's easier to do it by hand.

Comment: won't it show the  credentials on commit diff ?

Comment: Does lG1 immediately follow lF1, or are there more commits in between?

Comment: all are in sequence and lg1 has all the files but i have removed credential in that, so if only lg1 with all files move to (merge/rebase) master d1 it wont show any credential and I can have all files required in master without credential data

Comment: @atjoshi `git rebase` and `git filter-branch` rewrite history. Really it creates new history and says it was that way all along. Point is, there will be no commit showing the rewrite, it will be like the rewritten commits were always that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `git checkout master` and then [`git cherry-pick lG1`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to get that commit only onto master. Finally, you can once more `git push -f origin master`.

---

Update: Based on the OP's comments, it looks like we want to squash together the commits `lF1` and `lG1`, so that they look like one single commit which introduces the changes and `lF1` with the credentials removed in `lG1`. This can be accomplished by starting with the following commands.

```
git checkout abc
git rebase -i lE1
```

In the editor that shows up, change the `pick` to `squash` for the commit `lG1` and the save the file and quit the editor. Go through the remainder of the menus and then you should end up with the history you want, which you can then fast-forward merge into `master`.

Comment: But that is not giving me all the changed files in the commits from lg1

Comment: You said you only wanted the last commit unless I misread the question.  Are your saying there are changes in the last commit that don't get picked up by cherry pick?

Comment: Yes last commit (lF1 is with credential) and (lg1 i have removed credential) have some extra files which are not in master(D1), which I want to introduce them as well. So I want lg1 to merge with master D1, so here git diff will not show the credential

Comment: Thanks!!, Done  ... and acknowledged the effort  :)

Comment: @atjoshi, I'm glad we managed to clarify the question together. :)